# Cannot use FTP to transfer files on iPhone 4 over 3G

Tags: iphone, ftp

I have been using FTP on an iPhone 3GS in my app for almost a year with no problems. On my new iPhone 4 FTP fails all the time when using the 3G network. I have tried on 4 other iPhone 4's with the same result. I have tried multiple FTP servers with the same result.

Steps to Reproduce: 
1) Turn off wifi on iPhone 4.
2) Build and install code example SimpleFTPSample.
3) "Put" the lower right image (the larger the better. you may need to retry a few times to see the error)

You will see "Network write error". I added some debugging code to print out the actual error and this is what I got.

An error occured during FTP transfer
Description       : The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot allocate memory
Failure Reason    : Cannot allocate memory
Recover Suggestion: (null)
Error Domain      : NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Error Code        : 12

Any ideas for working around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in apples code back when I posted this